# I want to move the popup and hide the delete button from syncfusion scheduler asp.net core

Tags: modal-dialog, popup, scheduler, syncfusion, disable

I'm using asp.net core and syncfusion scheduler...

I want to drag the syncfusion scheduler popup

I tried this code

`$("#schedule_dialog_wrapper").addClass("e-draggable");`

and class is successfully changed but popup isn't move...

[image]

---

and I also want to hide the popup modal delete button

hi. I'm using asp.net core and syncfusion scheduler

I tried this code. but it can't change the class...
`$('#schedule_dialog_wrapper .e-footer-content').find('.e-event-delete').attr('e-disable', '');`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from Syncfusion.

Please find the below response for your queries.

**I want to drag the syncfusion scheduler popup**

You can drag the syncfusion scheduler popup by passing the popup element to Draggable constructor. Please find the below documentation for your reference.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/common/drag-and-drop#initializing-custom-draggable-element

**I also want to hide the popup modal delete button**

You can disable the delete action by setting EventSettings AllowDeleting property value as false.

https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/aspnetcore-js2/Syncfusion.EJ2.Schedule.ScheduleEventSettings.html#Syncfusion_EJ2_Schedule_ScheduleEventSettings_AllowDeleting

Comment: Thanks to the link you left, I succeeded in moving the pop-up
But there was another problem
When I first pop up in my scheduler, it comes out well in the middle of the screen, but once I close and reopen the pop-up window, the pop-up window often opens in a location other than the center.
Why is that?
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/Dialog/Positioning#/bootstrap5
I've referenced this link,
dragElement.style.left = 'center'; tried it this way.

Also
.schedule_dialog_wrapper {
left: 933.979px;
top: 273.882px;
}
I've tried this, but the pop-up window keeps popping up everywhere

Comment: And I saw the second link you left, but I couldn't find a solution.. Please help me a little more please

I'm using the editor template, and I want to hide the pop-up modal delete button according to the conditions I set

For example, if the logged in user is not an administrator, hide the delete button.

if (ViewBag.Admin != 1){ <tr>
<td class="e-textlabel">Type</td>
<td colspan="4">

The current editor template is organized like this...

Answer (score 0):

**When I first pop up in my scheduler, it comes out well in the middle of the screen, but once I close and reopen the pop-up window, the pop-up window often opens in a location other than the center.**

You can use allowDragging property of dialog to resolve the reported issue.

https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/aspnetcore-js2/Syncfusion.EJ2.Popups.Dialog.html#Syncfusion_EJ2_Popups_Dialog_AllowDragging

**[Index.cshtml]**

```
@if (ViewBag.Admin != 1)
{
    <ejs-schedule id="schedule" cssClass="hide-delete-button" height="550" selectedDate="new DateTime(2022, 2, 15)" popupOpen="Scheduler_OnPopupOpen_Delete_Button">
        <e-schedule-eventsettings dataSource="appData" AllowDeleting=false></e-schedule-eventsettings>
    </ejs-schedule>
}
else
{
    <ejs-schedule id="schedule" height="550" selectedDate="new DateTime(2022, 2, 15)" popupOpen="Scheduler_OnPopupOpen">
        <e-schedule-eventsettings dataSource="appData" AllowDeleting=true></e-schedule-eventsettings>
    </ejs-schedule>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Scheduler_OnPopupOpen_Delete_Button(args) {
        if (args.type === 'Editor') {
            var dragElement = document.getElementById('schedule_dialog_wrapper').ej2_instances[0];
            dragElement.allowDragging = true;
            args.element.querySelector('.e-event-delete').classList.add('e-hide');
        }
    }
    function Scheduler_OnPopupOpen(args) {

    }
</script>
```

**I want to hide the pop-up modal delete button according to the conditions I set For example, if the logged in user is not an administrator, hide the delete button.**

You can use the below customized codes and styles to hide the delete button, if the logged in user is not an administrator.

**[Index.cshtml]**

```
@if (ViewBag.Admin != 1)
{
    <ejs-schedule id="schedule" cssClass="hide-delete-button" height="550" selectedDate="new DateTime(2022, 2, 15)" popupOpen="Scheduler_OnPopupOpen_Delete_Button">
        <e-schedule-eventsettings dataSource="appData" AllowDeleting=false></e-schedule-eventsettings>
    </ejs-schedule>
}
else
{
    <ejs-schedule id="schedule" height="550" selectedDate="new DateTime(2022, 2, 15)" popupOpen="Scheduler_OnPopupOpen">
        <e-schedule-eventsettings dataSource="appData" AllowDeleting=true></e-schedule-eventsettings>
    </ejs-schedule>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Scheduler_OnPopupOpen_Delete_Button(args) {
        if (args.type === 'Editor') {
            var dragElement = document.getElementById('schedule_dialog_wrapper').ej2_instances[0];
            dragElement.allowDragging = true;
            args.element.querySelector('.e-event-delete').classList.add('e-hide');
        }
    }
    function Scheduler_OnPopupOpen(args) {

    }
</script>

<style>
    #schedule_dialog_wrapper .e-footer-content .e-btn.e-event-delete.e-hide {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```